# Perform a replace operation inside a ternary of an ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-class, ternary

Having an ng-class with a ternary like this:

```
<i ng-class="$ctrl.toCheck > 0 ? 'fa fa-square' : 'fa fa-circle'"></i>
```

`ctrl.toCheck` has the form of a string containing a number, like `"43.1"`.

The problem I have is when the number is greater than one thousand it looks like `"32,001.43"`.

In this case it cannot be tested against 0 to find out if it's greater or smaller.

My idea was to remove the commas so from `"32,001.43"` it will become `"32001.43"`, which tested in console is working fine.

But this doesn't work inside ng-class:

```
<i ng-class="$ctrl.toCheck.replace(/[,]/g,'') > 0 ? 'fa fa-square' : 'fa fa-circle'"></i>
```

it doesn't return any class.

I know that it could be changed to a numerical value in js file and send it like that to html, but is there a way to solve it in html only?

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Yes: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '/' not a primary expression at column ...`

Comment: accept it as string: `'/[,]/g'` and then parse it within some *check* function: `new RegExp(string)`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey can that be done in html?

Comment: @SudhirOjha that will take the string as true even if the value inside of it is negative (fact that should not happen)

Comment: @LeoMessi you need to parse it as integer somehow. This cannot be done in HTML alone, since angularjs doesn't evaluate it directly. Easiest solution: add a custom parser in your controller - `$ctrl.parse($ctrl.toCheck)` or a custom filter - `($ctrl.toCheck | toInteger)`

Comment: Here is a fiddle that demonstrates a similar situation using the parseFloat function. This requires exposing the parseFloat function in the controller to AngularJS as it otherwise doesn't recognize it. http://jsfiddle.net/KY5VL/3/